# CSS Row has no height?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

so I'm having trouble finding out why my css row has height on devices 992px in width and below but not on larger deivices.

Here my CSS:

```
.container
    width: 100%
    max-width: 1200px
    margin: 0 auto

.row
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-33">
                        <h3>Modular</h3>
                        <img src="assets/img/grid.png" alt="grid " />
                        <p>Take whatever parts you need and make your 
                            own tailored version of Architect...</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-33">
                        <h3>Responsive</h3>
                        <img src="assets/img/grid.png" alt="grid " />
                        <p>Take whatever parts you need and make your 
                            own tailored version of Architect...</p>                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-33">
                        <h3>Easy to use</h3>
                        <img src="assets/img/grid.png" alt="grid " />
                        <p>Take whatever parts you need and make your 
                        own tailored version of Architect...</p>                    
                    </div>                   
                </div>
```

A live example is at: http://www.architect-framework.com/

I see other frameworks have not got this issue, how?

Thanks

Comment: No, that class it correct. 33 stands for 33%

Comment: there is no defined height for that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

I just used clearfix

CSS:

```
.row:after 
    content: "."
    display: block
    clear: both
    visibility: hidden
    line-height: 0
    height: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.row::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```